# Passing get parameters in expressjs

Tags: javascript, express

```
var payload = {
    type: 'PAYLOAD'
  };  
app.get('/location', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/pages/locations.html',payload);
});
```

Hello , I'm new to expressjs , javascript and node , I can't manage to pass data through app.get , what I would like to be able to do  is to have the type of the payload as a GET parameter (so to see /locations?type=type_of_location ) , or at least to be able to access it from the javascript of the page locations.html.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are requesting `/locations?type=type_of_location` then you can access that `type` data with `req.query.type` because the `req.query` object has the data you need.

UPDATE:

**FIRST do this on your server:** Btw the only way to send `/locations?type=type_of_location` to the client is to redirect him and then send the file.

```
app.get('/location', function(req, res) {
    if(!req.query.type)
        res.redirect('/location?type=' + payload);
    else
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/pages/locations.html',payload);
});
```

If you want to do the opposite, send `/locations?type=type_of_location` to the client and extract the value of `type=type_of_location` then you can do that with javascript using `window.location.search` which returns `?type=type_of_location`.

**THEN do this on your client javascript:** Then have to process that result with a regular expression like:

```
let query = window.location.search;
let typeValue = /type=(.*)/.exec(query)[1]; // Extract the value
```

Comment: actually what I would like to have  is the opposite , so to send /locations?type=type_of_location   as the response

Comment: I'm sorry I must have had explained myself in the wrong way .

When app.get is called i would like to know how to send back to the client:  /locations?type=type_of_location , and to know how to access the type parameter  from the javascript of the client

Comment: Yes I've updated the code with the expressjs part. It will redirect the user to the same request but will add those parameters. Check my updated answer. Then, you use the javascript client's code to extract the content of `type` with a regular expression.